Issue with Plotting blocks in a boxplot
Trying to create a boxplot for this data however when I add blocks it comes up with lines instead of a boxplot
boxplot(Zn~Variety*Fertilizer+Block,data=data.df)
enter image description here
If I don't add blocks it works but I need blocks
boxplot(Zn~Variety*Fertilizer,data=data.df)
enter image description here
